# Calling a helper method in view dynamically during loop with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

```
            <table>                         
                <tr>                          
                    <th>Player Name</th>
                    <th>Club</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <% @myteam.each do |p| %>  
                <% @pd = playerDetails(p) %>       
                <tr>
                    <td><%= @pd.club %></td> 
                    <td><%= @pd.name %></td>
                    <td><button>Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>                     
            </table>
```

In the above I'm trying to get the players from myteam and put each in p. This works, I'm then trying to call a method on p called playerDetails and assign the values to @pd. This doesn't seem to work. Anyone know where exactly I've gone wrong? I only started learning ruby on rails today.

This is the playerDetails method by the way:

```
def playerDetails(pid)
  @pd = Player.where(:id => pid)
end
helper_method :playerDetails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pd will be an array.  Try this

```
@pd = Player.where(:id => pid).first
```

A suggestion - You may want to fill the @myteam array with Player instances instead of player ids.  It's faster to query for all the objects at once.